# PHPExcel Reading CSV Reading values incorrectly, values having special characters

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I am having hard time to read values form CSV correctly, the values are being fetched but the values contains special characters e. g �5�0�0�0�.
I have to perform some calculations on the values. Casting it to float/int didn't worked.

This is how i am doing it.

```
  $inputFileName=$this->fileName;

  /** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
  $included=require_once __SITE_PATH.DS.'assets'.DS.'script'.DS.'PHPExcel'.DS.'PHPExcel'.DS.'IOFactory.php';

  if( empty($included) )
  {
     header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request',true,400);
     echo 'xml lib not found';
     return false;
  }

  /** Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
  //$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

  /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
  $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

  /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

  /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
  $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

  /**  Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load  **/
  //$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);

  /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
  $this->fileHandler = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

  /*get the worksheet*/
  $objWorksheet = $this->fileHandler->getSheet(0);

  $this->eXjobs=$objWorksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Now when i loop $this->eXjobs & var_dump() the values i can see the special characters.

any help will be much appreciate.

Comment: Perhaps your CSV file is not encoded in `UTF-8`. You need to specify proper input encoding value through `$objReader->setInputEncoding('YOUR CSV ENCODING')`.  You can check the encoding e.g. using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Thanks for responding @putu. I have checked in notepad++ the csv encoding is UCS-2 LE BOM. I am checking why this error is appearing "Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `UCS-2 LE BOM' to `UTF-8' is not allowed " after i set $objReader->setInputEncoding("UCS-2 LE BOM");

Comment: `iconv` encoding name may differs slightly. Try `$objReader->setInputEncoding("UCS-2LE")`. If you still got error, convert the `csv` file to `UTF-8` manually using Notepad++ (menu: `Encoding --> Convert To UTF-8` then save) before passing to your PHP application. In this case, omit `setInputEncoding`.

Comment: Thanks Much @putu. I converted encoding of content of csv to UTF-8. & passed it to PHPExcel & it worked.